# CSS border - but width limited to text

Tags: width, border

I'm currently developing a site which requires headings as such:

[image: CSS border-bottom]

My initial idea was to do this with border-bottom, but how would I limit the width of the border so that it doesn't go all the way across? The border needs to stop when it gets to the text.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h1 {
    background-color: #fff;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

h1:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-top: -7px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The length of the border is decided by the size of the element it is bordering. You could create another `<div>` inline with the text with border-bottom: 1px; and the other borders set to 0. You could then change the margin or width of the `<div>` to alter the length of the line. Note that you'd have to set a width, because an empty `<div>` has a width of 0 by default, so won't display.

Another possible (but not recommended) way to do it would be to use a `<hr>` but these are not well supported in HTML 5, so I would choose the first method personally.

Answer (score 1):

A solution I can come up with is to give the title the same `background-color` as the page's background, and then to either `transform: scale()` the title up so that it overflows with the border of its parent, either scale the parent down so that its border hides behind the title's background.

See here for an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/WjRqC/1/

Oh, also, scaling can be replaced by making the title `position: relative` and moving it downwards a few pixels (and giving it a bit more vertical padding if you don't want the text too close to the line). Actually this is probably a better idea than scaling, because it's not CSS3, so it's more compatible.

Lookie here:
http://jsfiddle.net/7affw/1/